# how to create material design dialog box in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I'm a newbie in Google Material Design. I already read about Dialog components. But I don't know how to code to create dialog only material design lite without using any other framework or plugin.

Now I already create dialog box with jquery ui in my js file. But I want to change this jquery dialog box style to material style. I don't know how to make.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Material-Design-Lite.html
http://materializecss.com/modals.html#! Hope this links helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample code to know more about creating dialog boxes using mdl.

```
<html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button">Show Dialog</button>
         <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
         <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Delete this</h4>
         <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
             <p>
                  Do you really want to delete this??
             </p>
         </div>
         <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">No</button>
         </div>
      </dialog>
      <script>
           var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
           var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
           if (! dialog.showModal) {
                dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
            }
            showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.showModal();
            });
     dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
       });
  </script>
</body>
```